# How to increase the legend size in corrplot

Tags: r

In the following corrplot:

[image]

As you can see, the legend is not clear. How can I increase its size?

The script that I used to generate the plot:

```
dataset <- read.csv("/home/..../data.csv")
t <- table(dataset$LA_type, dataset$Method_type)
chisq <- chisq.test(t)
p <- corrplot(chisq$observed, is.cor = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can't duplicate without your data, but it's weird that there are a lot of tic marks but only two rows. Could it have anything to do with your ```is.cor = FALSE```? Should be ```is.corr = FALSE``` possibly.

Comment: If that's not it, you can try ```tl.cex = ``` some value other than the default 1.